# Regex pattern match and replace in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

**I have strings like follows :**

`Hi this is %1$s, product %2$s`
`Hi this is %2$s, product %2$s`

I want to replace `%1$s` by {0}, and `%2$s` by {1} and so on..

**I have tried to make:**

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: myString.count)
var regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "%[1-9]\\$s", options: [])
var newStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "XXXX")
```

**Anyone can help me, please!**

Comment: You can try this.

`let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%2$s ", with: "1")`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Quick question: What is the meaning of `[a-z]` at the start of your pattern? Did you try your regex with an online regex tool?

Comment: Ah sorry I have removed it later but forgot to update it here

Comment: The problem now is it repaces all occurrence with same number let us say {1} 
intended behavior is {1}, then {2}

Comment: So, *I want to replace %1$s by {0}, and %2$s by {1} and so on.* is wrong? Yo want to replace %1$s by {1}, and %2$s by {2}?

Comment: yes exactly {1} , {2} thank you for your reply the answer below solved it exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong, you have at the start `[a-z]`, so you aren't detecting anything.

Also, prefers utf16 count with NSStuff (because with NSString, it's UTF16)

```
let myString = "Hi this is %1$s, product %2$s Hi this is %2$s, product %2$s"

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: myString.utf16.count)
var regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "%(\\d+)\\$s", options: [])
var newStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "{$1}")
print(newStr)
```

Output:

```
$>Hi this is {1}, product {2} Hi this is {2}, product {2}
```

Some explanation on `%(\d+)\$s` (and then redo a `\` for Swift strings).
`%` : Detect "%"
`\d+`: Detect number (including 12 which weren't your case before)
`(\d+)`: Detect number, but in a capture group
`\$`: Detect "$" (need an escape because it's a special char in regex)
`s`: Detect "s"

So there are two groups: The whole (corresponding to the whole regex match), and the numbers. The first one would be $0, and the second one $1, that's why I used `{$1}` in the template.

NB: I used https://regex101.com to check the pattern.

With increment, you can't do it with the template. You have to enumerate all the matches, do the operation and replace.

```
var myString = "Hi this is %1$s, product %2$s Hi this is %2$s, product %2$s"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: myString.utf16.count)
var regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "%(\\d+)\\$s", options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: myString, options: [] , range: range)
matches.reversed().forEach({ aMatch in
    let fullNSRange = aMatch.range
    guard let fullRange = Range(fullNSRange, in: myString) else { return }
    let subNSRange = aMatch.range(at: 1)
    guard let subRange = Range(subNSRange, in: myString) else { return }
    let subString = myString[subRange]
    guard let subInt = Int(subString) else { return }
    let replacement = "{" + String(subInt + 1) + "}"
    myString.replaceSubrange(fullRange, with: replacement)
})
```

Comment: You just saved my day! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Larme Can I ask you a question 
what about if I want to subtract each no by 1 
ex: myString = "Hi this is {0}, product {1}, ..."