# Enumerate Through A String To Find Integers, Change then Replace Them - Swift

Tags: swift, string

I have a string that contains numbers.  The string may vary in length, the amount of numbers and the numbers may also be in different places.

I have written some code to find a number, add one to it and then put it back into the same position in the original string.  E.G. AA1BB becomes AA2BB.  Am new to swift so not entirely sure my code is the most efficient way to achieve this but it does work.

However, if I have a string like AA1BB2CC5H7, how could you add one to each number so the result would be AA2BB3CC6H8?  Am guessing some kind of loop, and ideally using regular expression.

The code I have so far which works on the first number only in a string is:

```swift
var testString = "AA1BB"

let testRange = testString.startIndex ..< testString.endIndex

let numberValue = testString [testString.range(of:"\\d+", options: .regularExpression) ?? testRange ] //edited to have default value in case there is no number found//

var numberAsInt = Int(numberValue) ?? 0 //change number from string to integer - edited to have a default number as a value//

// if number is not equal to 0 - edited, changed from NSNotfound//

if numberAsInt != 0  {
    //add one to the number value
    numberAsInt += 1
    //change new number value back to a string
    let numberAsString = String(numberAsInt)
    //assign the changed number "numberAsString" back into original variable into original place using a range (same range method set up as the numberValue variable)
    testString = testString.replacingCharacters(in: testString.range(of:"\\d+", options: .regularExpression)! , with: numberAsString)
    print (testString)
}
```

Any suggestions or advice on the best way to approach this problem would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010309/regex-pattern-match-and-replace-in-swift/61011698#61011698 ?

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1409687-enumeratematches

Comment: In Swift `numberValue` as well as `numberAsInt` is `nil` (in your case it will crash) if the range is not found respectively the string cannot be converted. `NSNotFound` is *objective-c-ish*

Comment: Thank you for the link @Larme! In searching for a solution I hadn't come across that answer!

Comment: Thanks @Vadian for the tip!

Comment: I have modified the code in my question (and indicated where via comments) to account for no number found in the string to avoid it crashing! Thanks to @Vadian for seeing the flaw in my original code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While answers mentioned in the comments are perfectly fine, let me offer an alternative by using our old friend `Scanner` instead of regex:

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    func byOffsettingNumbersBy(_ offset: Int) -> String {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: self)

        var output = ""

        while !scanner.isAtEnd {
            if let text = scanner.scanCharacters(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) {
                output += text
            } else if let int = scanner.scanInt() {
                output += String(int + offset)
            }
        }

        return output
    }

}

let strings = ["AA1BB2CC5H7", "AA1234BB2CC5H73A"]

let result = strings.map { $0.byOffsettingNumbersBy(1) }

print(result)

// Prints => ["AA2BB3CC6H8", "AA1235BB3CC6H74A"]
```

and of course, at its simpler form, something like this could be used:

```
let result = "A12B40".byOffsettingNumbersBy(-5)
```

---

For more on `Scanner`, [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/nsscanner/) has a great article on this

Comment: Thank you very much @Alladinian, never really thought about using a scanner. Running the function by passing it several strings at once is cool! As I'm a beginner seeing all these things is very useful!